# Error: installing tinytex (tinytex::install_tinytex()) in rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, pdflatex, tex, tinytex

I am trying to knit reports to pdf documents in rstudio.

I have successfully installed rtools and added it to my PATH, and also installed rmarkdown and tinytex. However whenever I run `tinytex::install_tinytex()` the following error about *tlmgr* is thrown.

> Error in system2("tlmgr", args, ...) : '"tlmgr"' not found

`xfun::session_info('tinytex')`

> R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042), RStudio 1.4.1717
>
> Package version:   graphics_4.1.0  grDevices_4.1.0 stats_4.1.0
> tinytex_0.32    tools_4.1.0       utils_4.1.0     xfun_0.23

I have installed tinytex with mush more relative ease in the past and have now tried this a gazillion times without any joy. Please any help will appreciated on this or at least a great guide on how to render tables in word(.docx) outputs.

Comment: You're saying that `Sys.getenv("PATH")` includes the directory in which tinytex is allegedly installed?

Comment: @r2evans  I do not think so, when I run ```.libPaths()``` the location is "C:/R/R-4.1.0/library" this where the package tinytex is, the path is very much different from ```Sys.getenv("PATH")``` returns.

Comment: something like this "C:\\R\\rtools40\\\\usr\\bin;C:\\R\\R-4.1.0\\bin\\x64;;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\R\\rtools40\\\\usr\\bin\\;C:\\Users\\XYZ\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\R\\rtools40\\\\usr\\bin\\;".

Comment: I don't see tinytext referenced in there, perhaps your statement *"added it to my PATH"* was premature? Realize that adding it to your PATH has no effect on running applications, so you may need to completely close and restart R *and* RStudio.

Comment: `.libPaths()` is for R packages, not executables. `tinytex` the R package installs utilities and such for the R package that are used (outside of R) to download, cache, maintain, etc, the LaTeX dependencies required to render your documents.

Comment: I meant added Rtools to my Path. I have also restarted R and RStudio multiple times with no luck.

Comment: What does `tinytex:::tinytex_root()` return?

Comment: ```tinytex:::tinytex_root()```returns ""

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know how I did this but let me just mention the obvious steps for anyone who meets such errors in the future.

I deleted *everything*, R and RStudio folders and emptied all folders from the recycle bin.

1. Reinstalled R
2. Reinstalled RStudio
3. Installed rmarkdown
4. Then tinytex::install_tinytex()

See the thing is I had done this a thousand times and I don't really know why this works now, but hey it's a free and new program, R.

And I will keep this open incase of any serious explanations and thanks for those that at least tried to help.

Comment: Thanks for adding this, sometimes it's helpful to know I'm not the only one with heisenbugs. =)